# How could I get a broadcast address on given port?

Tags: c#, networking

How can I get a broadcast address for a given port in C#?

Is using something in
`NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`
the right way?

Thank you

Clarification: I'd like to get an array of all broadcast addresses. Then I'd add a given port and return IPEndPoint[].

Comment: What do you mean by “given port”? If you mean something like 80 (HTTP), then that doesn't make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by broadcast address for a given port? Usually there's a broadcast IP for a given subnet.

Comment: I believe by port he means interface. So he want's the broadcast IP address of a given network interface.

Comment: That's right. In java there is getBroadcast() for InterfaceAddress object, but in C# there is no equivalent method for IPAddress or IPAddressInformation objects.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it by getting IP address, subnet mask and then doing IP OR ~SUBNET on each byte.

broadcast[i] = (byte)(ip[i] | ~sub[i]);

Comment: Also discussed here - https://www.countryipblocks.net/identifying-the-network-and-broadcast-address-of-a-subnet